# In Angular2, how can I subscribe to a custom components event?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component, which is a select drop down filled with offices:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'office-dropdown',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOffice" (ngModelChange)="handleChange()" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">Välj kontor</option>
      <option *ngFor="let office of offices$ | async" [ngValue]="office">
        {{office.officeName}}
      </option>
    </select>
    `
})
export class OfficeDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() filters = {};
  @Output() myCustomOnChange = new EventEmitter();
  offices$: Observable<Office[]>;
  selectedOffice = 0;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.offices$ = this.apiService.doRequest()
      .map(response => response.offices);
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.myCustomOnChange.emit(this.selectedOffice);
  }
}
```

And In the following component I'm using that office dropdown, which works fine, but I want to connect an observable stream to its custom `myCustomOnChange` event and subscribe to it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-select-employee',
  template: `
      <office-dropdown #officeDropDown (myCustomOnChange)="handleOffice($event)"></office-dropdown>
  `
})
export class AdminSelectEmployeeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('officeDropDown') officeDropDown;
  officeDropDown$: Observable<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.officeDropDown$ = Observable
      .fromEvent(this.officeDropDown, 'myCustomOnChange');

    this.officeDropDown$.subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(event); // This never gets logged
    });
  }

  handleOffice(office){
     console.log(office); // This works
  }
```

But the console.log in the ngAfterViewInit never gets logged.

Any ideas why?

**Edit** I have stripped down a lot of the surrounding code to just illustrate where I am having issues and not bloat my example with unnecessary code. In actuality, the second component is filled with a lot more html/ts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$event` is only the emitted value, not the observable and `@Output()` doesn't fire DOM events what `.fromEvent()` is for.

I would just use

```
  officeDropDown$: Observable<any>;
  private officeDropDown = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.officeDropDown$ = this.officeDropDown.asObservable();
    this.officeDropDown$.subscribe((event) => {
      console.log(event); // This never gets logged
    });
  }

  handleOffice(office){
    console.log(office); // This works
    this.officeDropDown.next(office); 
  }
```

Comment: What exactly does the asObservable() do? According to the docs asObservable is "An observable sequence that hides the identity of the source sequence." Can't wrap my head around what this actually means. Hiding identity?

Comment: Actually I don't know as well. I just have seen it mentioned that it's good practice to not publicly expose the `Subject` or other underlying source.

Comment: Ok will investigate this further, because your example also worked fine without .asObservable(), which made it possible to remove that variable completely!

Comment: That should definitely work, it's just about good practice. This way you can control who can use the `Subject` to emit events. When it's public someone also could do `someComponent.officeDropDown = null;`. It's just to make the API more stable.